# Logical Boolean Negation Operator Precedence and Association

Tags: php, boolean-logic, negation, boolean-algebra

here's my first question(s) on StackOverflow, and as such I imagine it *has* been asked here before, but everything I type into the search bar gives me different questions. (Or sometimes "no" results at all!)

I am learning on w3Schools, but I saw this seemingly simple code snippet which stirred up a small parcel of questions:

In essence the code says:

```
if(! test === FALSE)
  display("test successful!");
else
  display("test failed...")
```

"*test*" in this particular case returns a string on success or a (Boolean) **FALSE** upon failure.

Here are the questions that stirred within me.

1. As for the exclamation point (aka "Logical NOT" aka "Negation Operator") at the beginning of a conditional/if statement, is that:

   A) Applied to the whole statement within the parentheses?, or

   B) Only associated to "test"?

*Note: The negation operator's associativity may not change the outcome in this instance, but its associativity would matter in a case like: (! FALSE || TRUE), yeah?*

2. I understand how the Negation Operator works on Booleans, but how does the Negation Operator behave when faced with a (PHP) string?

   A) Does the negation operator's behavior change if the string happens to be something tricky like "true" or "0"?
3. Is **(! test === FALSE)** the same as **(test !== FALSE)**? Why didn't they just use "!=="?

**HERE** is the actual code in question:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
```

**Further PHP question**: Is there some sort of advantage to use *filter_var()* over *filter_input()* in this circumstance? Why did w3Schools use filter_var() and not filter_input()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you can see in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) operators in PHP have different priorities. It means:`!` applied to `$test` first.
2. According to the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), empty string `''` or `'0'` will be converted to `false`, otherwise `true`.
3. It is not the same. When `$test` equals to empty string `''` or `'0'` this two conditions have different behavior.